# Desplazar dos divs hacia lados opuestos

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, sass

Tengo dos divs, ambos con un botón debajo, que al clickearlo, debe desplazar el div de la izquierda, hacia la izquierda, y el div de la derecha, hacia la derecha, hasta ocultarse ambos totalmente. En el espacio resultante, emerge otro div en el centro, mostrando otra información, acompañado de un botón para cerrarlo y volver a la situación inicial.
Estoy usando jQuery y jQuery UI, pero lo único que consigo es que los divs a desplazarse desaparezcan repentinamente, como si el método `.hide()` no tuviera parámetros.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left" id="left-div">
        <p class="left-text">TEXT</p>
        <img src="video-left.png" alt="img" class="preview">
        <a class="btn-yellow" id="btn1">WATCH VIDEO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right-div">
        <p class="right-text">TEXT</p>
        <img src="video-right.png" alt="img" class="preview">
        <a class="btn-yellow" id="btn2">WATCH VIDEO</a>
    </div>

    <div class="iframe" id="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mmjlMgDSYFo" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <a id="close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2" aria hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="iframe" id="video2">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mmjlMgDSYFo" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <a id="close"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2" aria hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**SASS**

```
        .video-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 40.25%; /* 16:9 */
            padding-top: 25px;
            // max-width: 850px;
            height: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: flex;

            .left,
            .right {
                width: 50%;
                padding: {
                    top: 40px;
                    left: 10px;
                    right: 10px;
                }
                position: relative;

                p {
                    color: $white;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-align: left;
                    font-weight: $weight-bold;

                    &.right-text {
                        text-align: right;
                    }
                }

                .preview {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }

                .btn-yellow {
                    background-color: $yellow;
                    color: $green;
                    font-size: 26px;
                    font-weight: $weight-bold;
                    padding: 10px 25px;
                    transition: all .3s ease;

                    &:hover {
                        opacity: .7;
                    }
                }

                #btn1 {
                    float: left;
                }

                #btn2 {
                    float: right;
                }
            }

            .iframe {
                display: none;

                .video {
                    width: 74%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    top: 30px;
                    left: 140px;

                }

                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    transition: all .3s ease;

                    i {
                        color: $white;
                        font-size: 35px;
                        position: absolute;
                        right: 75px;
                    }

                    &:hover {
                        opacity: .7;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**JS**

```
$leftButton = $('#btn1');
$rightButton = $('#btn2');
$leftDiv = $('#left-div');
$rightDiv = $('#right-div');
$videoLeft = $('#video1');
$closeBtn = $('#close');

$(document).ready(function(){

   $leftButton.click(function(){

     $leftDiv.hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 600);

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo pude resolver con jQuery de la siguente manera:

```
function watchVideo(button, video) {
    button.click(function(){

        $leftDiv.animate({
            left: '-1450px',
        }, 1200);

        $rightDiv.animate({
            right: '-1450px',
        }, 1200);

        video.show(1200);

    });
}

function closeVideo(button, video) {
    button.click(function(){

        video.hide(1000);

        $leftDiv.animate({
            left: '0px',
        }, 1200);

        $rightDiv.animate({
            right: '0px',
        }, 1200);
    });
}

watchVideo($leftButton, $videoLeft);
watchVideo($rightButton, $videoRight);

closeVideo($closeBtn, $videoLeft);
closeVideo($closeBtn2, $videoRight);
```